# json dataframe to normal columns and rows

Tags: python

```
df=[{'id': '3253465436', 'attachments': {'data': [{'title': "Photos from  post"}]}},{'id': '248139211995219_440165304779172'}]
```

Above is my dataframe can some one help to make it as separate columns and rows please using python

Comment: Please be clearer. What's your expected result and what's the actual one you get ? What do you mean by separate columns and rows ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you tried it? What do you mean by “as separate columns and rows?”. Without more info we can’t help you and your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: expected output should be like a tabel with id and title headers followed by their values

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? What have you tried? Are you aware of [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)?

Comment: Above dataframe is the result of df=pd.json_normalize(json_load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
json_data=[{'id': '3253465436', 'attachments': {'data': [{'title': "Photos from  post"}]}},{'id': '248139211995219_440165304779172'}]
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)
df1 = df['id']
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['attachments.data'])
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df2[0])
print(pd. merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

output

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 3253465436 | Photos from post |
| 248139211995219_440165304779172 | NaN |

Comment: It works for me using below, what's the issue @LikhithaReddy

Comment: df=[{'id': '3253465436', 'attachments': {'data': [{'title': "Photos from  post"}]}},{'id': '248139211995219_440165304779172'}]. when i try to normalise again it gives erorr AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Weird it worked for me.. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Copy paste the code here and try